# Retrieving Google Contacts with specific extended property value

Tags: php, xml, google-contacts-api

I have a list of Google contacts which have assigned a value (id of related user in a database) as their extendedProperty. What I'm trying to do is retrieve a contact with specific id.

Here's the extendedProperty xml element:

```
<gd:extendedProperty name="user_id">
    <gd:value>@5</gd:value>
</gd:extendedProperty>
```

However when I send the following GET request:

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/?q=%405
```

it doesn't return any results...
It doesn't work even when I change the projection to 'property-user_id'.

When I tried sending a request with different fulltext query (e.g. name of the contact) it did return the correct contact so it looks as if the extendedProperties are ignored by the query.

Does anyone have any experience with this? When I searched for a similar issue, no one else had any problems with using fulltext queries on extended properties.

Comment: Did you tried to send your ID with a simple line ?
`<gd:extendedProperty name="user_id" value="@5"/>`

Comment: Yes I did. I also tried putting the value without the <value></value> tags... and it didn't work either.

Comment: I didn't know the `extendedProperty`. For my own use (I'm working on somethink like you), I am using custom fields (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/reference#gcUserDefinedField)

Comment: I thought about using custom fields as well, however you can't really hide them from the user (they are visible in the contact's information and you can edit them).

Comment: Still an issue ^^
Maybe the extendedProperty is not taken into consideration with the search ?
What you could try to do is : Get all contacts ; record only contacts that have this extendedProperty

Comment: That's what I did as a workaround, although this will be really slow once there are 100+ contacts. :( Anyway I went over the google contacts documentation almost 20 times now and I'm pretty sure that I did everything as they say. Almost seems like there's something missing, maybe they updated the api and didn't edit the documentation...